# Como ejecutar este programa

Tags: java, arraylist

Soy nuevo en `Java`. Tengo este programa que aun no logro entender.

Esta es la entrada del ejercicio.

```
[1,2,5,5,5,1,2,5,5,5]
```

Devo retornar:

```
[1,2,5]
```

> ¿Que deberia hacer para ejecutar ese programa, que variable declarar en el psvm?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Obra{
    
    public ArrayList<Integer> clases(ArrayList<Integer> categoriaDeLaObra){
        boolean repetido = false;
        
        ArrayList<Integer> categoriaUnicas = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < categoriaDeLaObra.size(); i++) 
        {
            repetido = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < categoriaUnicas.size(); j++) 
            {
                if ((categoriaDeLaObra.get(i)).equals(categoriaUnicas.get(j)))
                {
                    repetido = true;
                    break;
                }
                
            }
            if (!repetido)
                categoriaUnicas.add(categoriaDeLaObra.get(i));
        }
        return categoriaUnicas;
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: necesitas que clases sea `static` pra poder llamarlo desde un main. saludos.

Comment: necesitas llenar un ArrayList con los números en mención y pasarlo como parámetro a tu método clases, `System.out.println(clases(nombreDelArrayListConNumeros));`